# How to have different arguments when navigating to same destination but from different start point in android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I have three fragments fragment1, fragment2 and fragment3
Both fragment1 and fragment2 have an action to navigate to fragment3.
What i want to achieve is following:
The transition

> fragment1->fragment3 i want to pass parameter x of type X and y of
> type Y

and the transition

```
fragment2->fragment3 i want to pass parameter of z of type Z
```

Is it possible to achieve this and if yes how?

Comment: How would fragment 3 knows from which fragment it is reached out? so that it can retrieve the right data (x,y or z)?

Comment: I encourage you to use the `ViewModel` scope of your data instead of that.

Comment: Have you heard of `safe args`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will need to be able to receive all 3 arguments as nullable on Fragment3.

You can also provide a 4th parameter defining if you were coming from Fragment1 or if from Fragment2, and that way you'll know which nullable parameters you can expect to be non-null.

Comment: Yes it ended with your solution, where argument had nullable, or in this case some default values instead. But it would be nice to have different arguments for different paths